# One actor per simulated object, or a manager actor?

Tags: erlang, actor

I'm developing a simulation that will feature many entities constantly updating, perhaps 30 times a second. Let's imagine we have 1000 entities, each of which has a velocity, and consequently a position that must be updated every tick.

So, how would you implement this using the actor model? I'm not necessarily using Erlang for this project, but for the sake of argument, let's just say I am. Would you have an actor for each of these entities? Or would you have a "manager" actor that maintains and updates a list of these entities?

[Learn You Some Erlang says](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/introduction#kool-aid):

> It is true that Erlang processes are very light: you can have hundreds
>   of thousands of them existing at the same time, but this doesn't mean
>   you have to use it that way just because you can. For example,
>   creating a shooter game where everything including bullets is its own
>   actor is madness. The only thing you'll shoot with a game like this is
>   your own foot. There is still a small cost in sending a message from
>   actor to actor, and if you divide tasks too much, you will make things
>   slower!

So that seems to suggest that managers would be better. Or is there a third option that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You say it! there is not one single good solution.

Now to be more helpful, and with the few background I have, I think you should look at these aspects of your project:

You say simulation. If you need to refresh a collection of entities every 30ms, first work to simplify the operations and the data model, and only second think how you can traverse the collection of data efficiently.

On the other end, if you have a huge and/or evolving collection of objects, with trivial algorithm/data model, then look at smarter data structure than lists, take care of the data copy...

If you use a multi-core (or a cluster) then think to have your entities grouped in several super entities in order to take advantage of parallelism, managing them in separate processes.

Next think if these groups can help you to reduce the number of evaluation (have an adaptive time slice? evaluation on demand? ...) .

Last, I think than generally speaking, Erlang is compact and easy to refactor, so take advantage of this an define some functional steps, and for each of them,

> make them work, make them right and make then fast (Kent Beck ?)

For the last step you can get some help from the profiling tools such as fproof

Courage :o)

Answer (score 0):

I think Learn You Some Erlang is making a bit of a premature optimization blunder here.  You should use which ever abstraction makes the most sense to you, measure any problems, and refactor if necessary.  Personally, I believe modeling each particle as its own actor would be the easiest to deal with, and is also the most idiomatic approach for the Actor model. Practically, however, you should do whatever floats your boat.